# make width and height of elements fill the screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

If you look at my document here: http://featuredfotografer.com/

you will see that there is a gutter to the left, and the width of both the .Codemirror div and the #header div are not filling the screen.

How can I do this with css or jquery (if i have to)?

I have already applied width:100% and height:100% to the corresponding elements and it doesn't work. Something to do with the codemirror plugin overriding it, but how can I take control?

**UPDATE:**

width fixed, what about height?

Comment: style wrapper: position=relative. https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/3591

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your docs.css have a `max-width: 64.3em` for body.

Remove it, or set `max-width: 100%`

```
#body { max-width: 100% }    
#header { position: fixed; z-index: 20 }    
.CodeMirror { padding-top: 32px }
```

Comment: works on width, but not height. how can i fix the height issue?

Comment: #cont, #cont .CodeMirror {height: 100%;}

Comment: it's broke when your code have more height than the window, right? i will fix it for you

Comment: try remove the #cont,#cont .CodeMirror height 100%, and try my edited answer css

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work: http://featuredfotografer.com/?f=longfile.html ..... the height was uncontrolled so it became as long as it needed to be

Comment: i can do it with javascript if i have to but that is pretty sloppy

Comment: try put #header with position fixed and .CodeMirror with padding-top: 32. With these rules works correctly for me: (

Comment: it's not the same thing, but i guess it works: http://featuredfotografer.com/?f=longfile.html thanks

Comment: :P any doubt / problem just leave another comment :D

Answer (score 1):

Try avoiding using inline styles so much in the future... Makes it a pain to help :\
 Anyway, here ya go:

modifications to your inline styles:

[image]

updated codemirror.css:

```
.CodeMirror {
line-height: 1.4em;
font-family: monospace;
font-size:12px;
pointer:text;

/* Necessary so the scrollbar can be absolutely positioned within the wrapper on Lion. */
position: relative;
/* This prevents unwanted scrollbars from showing up on the body and wrapper in IE. */
overflow: hidden;
height: 100%;
top: -33px;
}

.CodeMirror-scroll {
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
/* This is needed to prevent an IE[67] bug where the scrolled content
is visible outside of the scrolling box. */
position: relative;
outline: none;
height:100%;
pointer:text;
}

/* Vertical scrollbar */
.CodeMirror-scrollbar {
float: right;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;

/* This corrects for the 1px gap introduced to the left of the scrollbar
by the rule for .CodeMirror-scrollbar-inner. */
margin-left: -1px;
}
.CodeMirror-scrollbar-inner {
/* This needs to have a nonzero width in order for the scrollbar to appear
in Firefox and IE9. */
width: 1px;
}
.CodeMirror-scrollbar.cm-sb-overlap {
/* Ensure that the scrollbar appears in Lion, and that it overlaps the content
rather than sitting to the right of it. */
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
float: none;
right: 0;
min-width: 12px;
}
.CodeMirror-scrollbar.cm-sb-nonoverlap {
min-width: 12px;
}
.CodeMirror-scrollbar.cm-sb-ie7 {
min-width: 18px;
}

.CodeMirror-gutter {
position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
z-index: 1;
background-color: #f7f7f7;
border-right: 1px solid #eee;
min-width: 2em;
height: 100%;
}
.CodeMirror-gutter-text {
color: #aaa;
text-align: right;
padding: .4em .2em .4em .4em;
white-space: pre !important;
}
.CodeMirror-lines {
padding: .4em;
white-space: pre;
cursor: text;
margin-top: 33px;
}
.CodeMirror-lines * {
/* Necessary for throw-scrolling to decelerate properly on Safari. */
pointer-events: none;
}

.CodeMirror pre {
-moz-border-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-o-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; background: transparent;
font-family: inherit;
font-size: inherit;
padding: 0; margin: 0;
white-space: pre;
word-wrap: normal;
line-height: inherit;
color: inherit;
}

.CodeMirror-wrap pre {
word-wrap: break-word;
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-break: normal;
}
.CodeMirror-wrap .CodeMirror-scroll {
overflow-x: hidden;
}

.CodeMirror textarea {
outline: none !important;
}

.CodeMirror pre.CodeMirror-cursor {
z-index: 10;
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
border-left: 1px solid black;
border-right: none;
width: 0;
}
.cm-keymap-fat-cursor pre.CodeMirror-cursor {
width: auto;
border: 0;
background: transparent;
background: rgba(0, 200, 0, .4);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#6600c800, endColorstr=#4c00c800);
}
/* Kludge to turn off filter in ie9+, which also accepts rgba */
.cm-keymap-fat-cursor pre.CodeMirror-cursor:not(#nonsense_id) {
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
}
.CodeMirror pre.CodeMirror-cursor.CodeMirror-overwrite {}
.CodeMirror-focused pre.CodeMirror-cursor {
visibility: visible;
}

div.CodeMirror-selected { background: #d9d9d9; }
.CodeMirror-focused div.CodeMirror-selected { background: #d7d4f0; }

.CodeMirror-searching {
background: #ffa;
background: rgba(255, 255, 0, .4);
}

/* Default theme */

.cm-s-default span.cm-keyword {color: #708;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-atom {color: #219;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-number {color: #164;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-def {color: #00f;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-variable {color: black;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-variable-2 {color: #05a;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-variable-3 {color: #085;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-property {color: black;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-operator {color: black;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-comment {color: #a50;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-string {color: #a11;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-string-2 {color: #f50;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-meta {color: #555;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-error {color: #f00;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-qualifier {color: #555;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-builtin {color: #30a;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-bracket {color: #cc7;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-tag {color: #170;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-attribute {color: #00c;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-header {color: blue;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-quote {color: #090;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-hr {color: #999;}
.cm-s-default span.cm-link {color: #00c;}

span.cm-header, span.cm-strong {font-weight: bold;}
span.cm-em {font-style: italic;}
span.cm-emstrong {font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;}
span.cm-link {text-decoration: underline;}

div.CodeMirror span.CodeMirror-matchingbracket {color: #0f0;}
div.CodeMirror span.CodeMirror-nonmatchingbracket {color: #f22;}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you should use the next styles as is adviced in the codemirror documentation (http://codemirror.net/demo/resize.html):

```
.CodeMirror {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  height: auto;
}
.CodeMirror-scroll {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

After doing it, you should define the margins in the `body` tag, i.e, if you have a border of `1px` in the `body` you should define `margin-bottom: 2px;` and `margin-right: 2px;` there.

Answer (score 0):

Add `max-width:100% !important` to your `html,body` CSS as docs.css from codemirror sets a `max-width:64em` on the body.

Comment: don't ever use !important. dont ever.

Comment: @hawaii.five-0 - out of curiosity, why not?

Comment: @hawaii.five-0 bs, there's nothing wrong with using important in some cases. Rearranging your CSS is best but sometimes `!important` is just plain easier.

Comment: so for this issue, there is more views but i don't recommend to use !import, work with it is harmful but some developers recommend also this approach. but exists also different approaches how to avoid this hack.

Comment: in cases like this where you use a 3rd party script / widget, you may not have any other option but to use `!important`. In your own CSS you should try an avoid it if you can.

Comment: help with the height would be good too if you have a solution for that

Comment: I added a solution to your other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209692/making-combined-height-equal-to-the-height-of-the-browser-window/11209988#11209988