# making combined height equal to the height of the browser window

Tags: html, css

http://featuredfotografer.com/

The .Codemirror div in combination with the #header div takes up more height than the height of the browser. How can I make them have a combined height of 100% of the browser window so I have no scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> making combined height equal to the height of the browser window

Just add this snippet of code. It will set your content to `100%` of browser window.

```
body,html {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Also you can check [this](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=2&cid=BAD95).

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach to this. You can make a small 1px high and 30px wide image that looks like the background behind the line numbers and apply it to the `body` with a `repeat-y` and aligned `left`. Remove the `height:100%` on the `.CodeMirror` div

Alternately you can

add `<div class="CodeMirror-gutter bodyGutter"></div>` just before your closing `</body>` tag and add this to your CSS, and also again remove the `height:100%` on the `.CodeMirror` div:

```
.bodyGutter {
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 20px;
  left: -8px;
}
```

This is also adding a fake gutter to your body and pushing it to the background to give the fake appearance of 100% height.